# [C#]Add XSL reference in XMLDocument

Tags: xml, xslt, c#-2.0

I am creating an XML document from my C# code. I need to add the XSL reference in my XML document. My code is:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
if (!File.Exists(fileName))
{
    XmlDeclaration dec = xDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
    xDoc.AppendChild(dec);
    **[Need to add code to add the XSL reference e.g. - <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"?> ] **
    XmlElement root = xDoc.CreateElement("Errors");
    xDoc.AppendChild(root);
}
else
{
    xDoc.Load(fileName);
}
XmlElement errorLogStart = xDoc.CreateElement("ErrorLog");
XmlElement errorText = xDoc.CreateElement("Message");
errorText.InnerText = message;
errorLogStart.AppendChild(errorText);
xDoc.DocumentElement.InsertBefore(errorLogStart, xDoc.DocumentElement.FirstChild);

FileStream fileXml = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
xDoc.Save(fileXml);
```

I need to add the following line - `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cdcatalog.xsl"?>` in my XML document. How can I do it? Couldn't find much through google.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
var xDoc = new XmlDocument();
var pi = xDoc.CreateProcessingInstruction(
    "xml-stylesheet", 
    "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"cdcatalog.xsl\"");
xDoc.AppendChild(pi);
```